# How can I make a service dependent on another service value

Tags: angularjs

Ok, so I have this service that is dependent on another service value that the user can change in the app interface. Something like this:

```
app.service('Applications', ['$resource', 'URL',
    function ($resource, URL) {
        var applicationsResource = $resource(URL + '/applications/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function(body, header) {
                    var response = angular.fromJson(body);
                    return response.data.applications;
                }
            }
        });

        var applications = applicationsResource.query(function() {
            applications.current = applications[0];
        });

        return applications;
    }
]);

app.service('Users', ['$resource', 'URL', 'Applications',
    function ($resource, URL, Applications) {
        return $resource(URL + '/users/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                headers: {
                    'User': Applications.current.username,
                    'Pass': Applications.current.password
                },
                transformResponse: function(body, header) {
                    var response = angular.fromJson(body);
                    return response.data.users;
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Example of working controller code:

```
app.controller('usersController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'URL', 'Applications',
    function ($scope, $resource, URL, Applications) {
        $scope.users = [];

        $scope.reload = function() {
            $scope.loading = true;
            var usersResource = $resource(URL + '/users/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true,
                    headers: {
                        'User': Applications.current.username,
                        'Pass': Applications.current.password
                    },
                    transformResponse: function(body, header) {
                        var response = angular.fromJson(body);
                        return response.data.users;
                    }
                }
            });
            $scope.users = usersResource.query(function() {
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
            /*
            // after injecting Users, this is what I want to do, instead of what's above
            $scope.users = Users.query(function() {
                $scope.userTable.reload();
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
            */
        };

        $scope.$watch('Applications.current', function (newApplication, oldApplication, scope) {
            if (newApplication && newApplication !== oldApplication) {
                scope.reload();
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

I want to replace that usersResource with my Users service, but that's where I'm stuck now.

The issue is that no matter what I do, the Applications.current on the Users service is always null. (I only make use of this service after making sure that Applications.current is not null on the controller)

If I move the resource directly to the controller, it works, but I want to move these away from the controllers.

Any tips on how to fix or improve this?

Comment: Please post `User` call and relevant controller code

Comment: Edited with a working controller code to demonstrate what I want.

Comment: ok, please post how do you call services when it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I have added a comment with the intended code

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `$resource` is async and you call `Users` service before actually you got response from server and populated `applications.current`. This a reason why `Applications.current` is `null` into `Users` service.

In your case I would use `Uses` service into `Applications`:

```
app.service('Applications', ['$resource', 'URL', 'Users',
function ($resource, URL, Users) {
        var applicationsResource = $resource(URL + '/applications/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function(body, header) {
                    var response = angular.fromJson(body);
                    return response.data.applications;
                }
            }
        });

        var applications = applicationsResource.query(function() {
            applications.current = applications[0];

                     // call the Users
                     Users.query(applications.current) /**/

                    return /* ... */; 

        });

        return applications;
    }
]);
```

Comment: I don't call the Users service before getting any results from the server. On the controller I have something like this: `if (Applications.current) $scope.users = Users.query(function() { /* fails because Applications.current is null */ })`

Comment: Did you check that `Applications.current` has `username/pswd` on controller?

Comment: See my edit, I think you need use Users into Applications since Applications is a root service

Comment: That doesn't really work because the current application can change. (that's why I have that watch in the controller)